# Is it possible to make the build stage parallel?

Tags: aws-copilot

Is it possible to make the build stage parallel?
today the build stage builds and deploys all the images in a sequence, which takes quite a lot of time. it would save a lot of time if each image will be built in parallel to the others (same as the deploy stage).

Answer (score 0):

The deploy stage *does* run in parallel, unless you opt to deploy them in order with the [`stages.deployments`](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/pipeline/#stages-deployments) field in your pipeline manifest.

As for the build stage, you can make changes to your own pipeline's buildspec, specifically in this block:

```
for env in $pl_envs; do
  tag=$(sed 's/:/-/g' <<<"${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID##*:}-${env}" | rev | cut -c 1-128 | rev)
  for svc in $svcs; do
  ./copilot-linux svc package -n $svc -e $env --output-dir './infrastructure' --tag $tag --upload-assets;
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Cloudformation stack and config files were not generated. Please check build logs to see if there was a manifest validation error." 1>&2;
    exit 1;
  fi
  done;
  for job in $jobs; do
  ./copilot-linux job package -n $job -e $env --output-dir './infrastructure' --tag $tag --upload-assets;
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Cloudformation stack and config files were not generated. Please check build logs to see if there was a manifest validation error." 1>&2;
  exit 1;
  fi
  done;
done;
```